# somone ask to borrow account

Tags: scams, cash

Someone i barely know said he wants to move into my country and wants to borrow my account to transfer some cash as he does not want to bring cash in hands. Is it safe for me to give him my account number

Comment: Ask yourself this: why doesn't he do it like everyone else from his country that wants to transfer cash to your country?

Comment: perhaps.. and if i have 2 different bank accounts..and one of the bank account is scammed..will the other account be at risk too

Comment: **Someone i barely know**, hmmm, some prince from Nigeria?

Comment: You barely know them, so it's safe to assume that they barely know you. Therefore, they have no reason to trust you with nontrivial sums of their money, which in turn means this is some sort of a scam.

Comment: @Nialljamespayne Don't worry about a second account being at risk.  Worry about **you** being at risk.  If you own the account and something illegal goes down, you're on the hook. The fact that your second account remains untouched will not prevent **you** going to prison (or just owing a lot of money) for what happened with the first.

Answer (score 9):

Bank accounts (or other pay-service equivalent) are generally not designed to be shared with people who are not registered directly on the account. If you share your account with someone else you can and will be held liable for anything they do on/with the account. This includes being held responsible for any debt, fraud, illegal activity (money laundering, trying to hide financial activity from any authority), etc.

If something illegal or questionable is done, you will be hard pressed to prove you were not a willing accessory or accomplice to any crime. Sharing your account information willingly would be evidence that you were complicit - you do not want to have to figure out how you would prove you didn't know what they were going to do with it.

If a debt is incurred (passing a bad check, overdraw, reversed transaction, etc.) it will not matter that someone else incurred the debt, you can still be held liable because it is your account. Depending on your jurisdiction, having one account closed for debt/fraud can trigger action to be taken on your other accounts, but this varies by location and by account providers (banks often share data, sometimes directly and sometimes through companies like ChexSystems in the US). The total you can be held liable for is effectively limitless, but obviously varies by account type.

Long story made short: sharing accounts is generally a large risk for the person offering to share the account, and pretty risky for the person getting to use the account as well (though the risk is larger for the account owner).

If this were family or a close friend, I'd still strongly advise against it. If this is something you hardly know, the answer is even easier: **no, do not share your account!**